# Can you login to a different aws OU with master account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I know i can create roles and switch between them and I've done a bit a research and it seems the answer is no but I just wanted to make sure.

So i was hoping that when a account joins my organisation, there would be some way for me to use my master account to login to the new OU, e.g. without me having to login and create new roles / users etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the new account from your existing “master” account, the new account that joins your org needs to have a role which allows cross-account access from your master account.

Its worth noting that many organizations automate the creation of accounts, and then use CloudFormation to configure the account (which you could use to create a cross account role for you to use to access the new account). You can learn more about this in the AWS tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-organizations-to-automate-end-to-end-account-creation/).

Comment: ok thanks for that. I guess the answer is yes and no, yes, if your creating a new OU, and you would need to create a new root user as part of that, and whilst your doing that you can also create the roles, that will let the master account switch roles. And no, if its an exisiting account